# Ayushya Suktam is said to of Yajur Veda. Can someone provide the Vedic Shakha, the Kanda-Suktha number and link to its translation if possible?

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda

Many Vedic Suktas have popular names, but the Vedic literature has Shakha-Kanda-Suktam Number with Devata, Metre, Group, Rishi and more. Some suktas are a collection of hymns/verses from various suktas. In this way, Ayushya Suktam is said to of Yajur Veda. Can someone provide the Vedic Shakha, the Kanda-Suktha number and link to its translation if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mantras are not found in the extant Krishna Yajurveda (Taittiriya at least). Reference to the mantras and the homa procedure are found in the Grihya Sutras. In particular the Agniveshya Grihya Sutra 2.5.3 describes the process and the mantras.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also baudhayana sUtra बोधायनगृह्यसूत्रे तृतीयप्रश्ने सप्तमोऽध्याये
[image: baudhAyana sUtra बोधायनगृह्यसूत्रे तृतीयप्रश्ने सप्तमोऽध्याये]